# My Table View is not showing data

Tags: iphone

I am using a tableView in my ViewController as IBOutlet. I have implemented all the delegates methods and data source methods. But the data is not showing there...what i did wrong there...

Please help...

Comment: first welcome to StackOverFlow.:) and second share your code..without code we can not help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the delegates and Data Source from IB to Files Owner. please check that

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use refer [Link](http://development-iphone-app.blogspot.in/2011/10/uitableview-example.html) as UITableView Example and correct ur mistake. If u unable to this then show us code.

So we can help you.